# Demonstration Schur's lemma(Linear algebra)

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I was reading "Linear Algebra" of G.Strang(4ed) and I encountered Schur's lemma.
The statement and the proof go like this

> Suppose $A$ is a complex square matrix.
>   Then there exists a unitary matrix $U$ such that
>   $$U^{-1}AU$$
>   is triangular.

**Proof**
Suppose $A$ is a $4$ by $4$ matrix.
$A$ has at least one unit eigenvector $x_1$, which we place in the first column of $U$.
By the Gram-Schmidt process, there exists a unitary $U_1$ such that
$${U_1}^{-1}AU_1=
\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda_1 &*&*&*\\
0&*&*&*\\
0&*&*&*\\
0&*&*&*
\end{bmatrix}$$
Now consider the $3$ by $3$ submatrix in the lower right-hand corner.
It has a unit eigenvector $x_2$, which becomes the first column of a unitary matrix $M_2$.
$$\text{Set }
U_2=\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&0\\
0\\
0&&M_2\\
0
\end{bmatrix}
\qquad
\text{then }
\qquad
{U_2}^{-1}{U_1}^{-1}AU_1U_2=
\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda_1 &*&*&*\\
0&\lambda_2&*&*\\
0&0&*&*\\
0&0&*&*
\end{bmatrix}$$

In a similar fashion,
$${U_3}^{-1}{U_2}^{-1}{U_1}^{-1}AU_1U_2U_3=
\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda_1 &*&*&*\\
0&\lambda_2&*&*\\
0&0&\lambda_3&*\\
0&0&0&*
\end{bmatrix}$$

**Here is the question**:
Can anyone give me a nontrivial(e.g. non-diagonal) matrix which demonstrate this lemma, with the corresponding $U_1$, $U_2$, $U_3$ and $T$?

Comment: Haha I feel like every single author has a different statement they call "Schur's lemma", this is my first time seeing this one! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $4\times 4$ matrix is too complicated for us to demonstrate the lemma as an example.
Instead, consider the following $3\times 3$ matrix;
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
2&1&-2\\
1&0&0\\
0&1&0
\end{bmatrix}$$
It has $\lambda=1,-1,2$ as eigenvalues.
Choose $\lambda_1=1$.
The corresponding eigenvector of length $1$ is
$$x_1=\frac1{\sqrt3}\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}\tag{1}$$
Since we have
$$Ax_1=x_1,\tag{2}$$
construct a matrix $U_1$ which have $x_1$ as the first column.
And impose $U_1$ to be unitary.
We may set, for example,
$$U_1=\begin{bmatrix}
\frac1{\sqrt3} &\frac1{\sqrt2} &\frac1{\sqrt6} \\
\frac1{\sqrt3} &-\frac1{\sqrt2} &\frac1{\sqrt6} \\
\frac1{\sqrt3} &0    &-\frac2{\sqrt6} 
\end{bmatrix}$$
Note that $U_1$ is not unique.
From (2), we have
$$AU_1=U_1
\begin{bmatrix}
1&*&*\\
0&*&*\\
0&*&*\\
\end{bmatrix}\tag{3}$$
Let the unkown matrix on the right hand side be $B$.
We get
$$B={U_1}^{-1}AU_1=\begin{bmatrix}
1& \frac1{\sqrt6} &\frac3{\sqrt2} \\
0& 0   &\sqrt3   \\
0& \frac2{\sqrt3}&1
\end{bmatrix}.$$
Let
$$\bar B=\begin{bmatrix}
0   &\sqrt3\\
\frac2{\sqrt3} &1
\end{bmatrix}.$$
It has $\lambda=-1,2$.
(Note that $A$ and $B$[defined as in (7)] have exactly the same eigenvalues, which is trivial since $A$ and $B$ are similar).
Choose $\lambda_2=-1$.
The corresponding unit eigenvector is
$$\overline{x_2}=\frac12\begin{bmatrix}
\sqrt3\\-1\tag{4}
\end{bmatrix}$$
We have
$$\bar B\overline{x_2}=-\overline{x_2}.\tag{5}$$
Let $\overline{U_2}$ have $\overline{x_2}$ as the first column.
Again, $U_2$ is unitary:
$$\overline{U_2}=\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\sqrt3}2 &\frac12\\
-\frac12  &\frac{\sqrt3}2
\end{bmatrix}.$$
(Here, $\overline{U_2}$ is not unique, but we only have two possibilities.)
From (5), we have
$$\bar B\overline{U_2}=\overline{U_2}
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 &*\\
0 &*
\end{bmatrix}.\tag{6}$$
Let the unknown matrix on the right hand side be $\bar C$.
We get
$$\bar C=\overline{U_2}^{-1}\bar B\overline{U_2}=\begin{bmatrix}
-1 &\frac1{\sqrt3}\\
0 &2
\end{bmatrix}.$$
Let $B$, $U_2$ and $C$ be $3\times 3$ matrices and let $x_2$ be a column vector in $\mathbb R^3$ such that
$$B=\begin{bmatrix}
1&0\\0&\bar B
\end{bmatrix}
,\quad
U_2=\begin{bmatrix}
1&0\\0&\overline{U_2}
\end{bmatrix}
,\quad
C=\begin{bmatrix}
1&0\\0&\bar C
\end{bmatrix}
,\quad
x_2=\begin{bmatrix}
0\\\overline{x_2}
\end{bmatrix}.
\tag{7}$$
Then (6) reduces to
$$BU_2=U_2C.\tag{8}$$
By (3) and (8),
$$C={U_2}^{-1}BU_2={U_2}^{-1}{U_1}^{-1}AU_1U_2.$$
Note that $C$ is a triangular matrix.